# What is the difference between doing a "link:http://www.example.com" google search and the "links to your site" in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I've tried to do two kinds of searches which I had previously thought were a source of the same data, but are apparently different.

The first is doing a google search that looks like `link:http://mydomain.com` which I assumed returned all of the links indexed by Google Crawler which linked to my page:

[image: Google external link search]

The second is within Webmaster Tools in the `Links to Your Site` functionality:

[image: Webmaster Tools External Links]

The reason I'm confused by this is that it appears that there don't seem to be as many in-bound links appearing in the `link:` google search as there are appearing in the `Links on Your Site` functionality in Webmaster Tools, so it seems to me that these two functions are not referring to the same data as I previously assumed.

If this is not the case, then what are each of these referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're basically both from the "same data." Google reveals what Google reveals, which in general, seems to be *some* links publicly for anyone to see and *more* links privately for those who have confirmed they have access to the site. Google doesn't even reveal *every* link it knows about to webmasters; it's all a combination of choice and physical limitations. [Here Matt Cutts explains](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-provides-backlink-tool-for-site-owners/) some of the different limitations and reasons for those limitations.